# Add script tag to all django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, usersnap

My Django app contains 100+ HTML templates (should've made a web app). I need to add a user feedback widget similar to Usersnap. One way is to add a script tag to all of the 100+ template files and make sure it's added in all future files as well.

Is there a way to add the script tag without repeating the code 100+ times?

Comment: Template inheritance https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Bless you man! Spent way tooo long on this already